# What do I need to do to build (parts of) WebRTC for Android (NDK)? It can't find C++ headers

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, webrtc, ndk-build

I'm trying to build some features of WebRTC into a project. We had previously gotten some C-only code functioning, and I'm trying to add more files. The new files are C++, and when I run `ndk-build` I'm getting errors related to the C++ includes:

```
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: zello.webrtc <= audio_frame.cc
In file included from libwebrtc/jni/libwebrtc/api/audio/audio_frame.cc:15:
libwebrtc/jni/libwebrtc/rtc_base/checks.h:36:10: fatal error: 
  'sstream' file not found
#include <sstream>
         ^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

My `Application.mk` files includes

```
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a arm64-v8a x86 x86_64
APP_OPTIM := release
APP_PLATFORM := android-15
APP_STL := c++_shared
APP_CPPFLAGS := -fexceptions
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := clang
```

and my `Android.mk` file includes

```
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS := -std=c++11
LOCAL_CPP_EXTENSION := .cpp .cc
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
    webrtc-jni.cpp \
    libwebrtc/api/audio/audio_frame.cc \
    ...
```

I've tried explicitly adding

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(NDK_ROOT)/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include
```

but that just leads to more errors about undefined functions, and doesn't seem like it should be necessary in the first place. I've also tried specifying all the other values for `APP_STL` with no effect.

I am building with NDK 16b, since we still need to support `armeabi` devices.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

EDIT: When I run `ndk-build V=1` I see that `ndk-build` is probably using the wrong STL header directory:

```
... -I${NDK_ROOT}/sources/cxx-stl/system/include ...
```

but I've defined `APP_STL` as `c++_shared`, which I *think* should be looking in a different directory.

Comment: The supported way to build WebRTC is with their own build tools on Linux. You can do it in a virtual machine if necessary. The resulting static libraries can be used elsewhere. It is a pain to prepare ndk-build compatible environment for WebRTC, and you never know that you have all build parameters set correctly. There are quite a few source files that are not really compiled in the official build, but still nobody had the courage to delete.

Comment: We're really trying to avoid using the whole WebRTC product. We don't need most of it; we're only using a small portion of its audio processing capabilities.

Comment: As I said, after one-time setup you get static libraries that you can use the way you like. It's not worth the hassle to setup an alternative build scheme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to put the `APP_STL` definition in the top-level `Application.mk` file. Our app is structured like

```
top/Application.mk
top/Android.mk
top/...
top/submodule1/jni/Application.mk
top/submodule1/jni/Android.mk
top/submodule1/jni/...
top/submodule2/jni/Application.mk
top/submodule2/jni/Android.mk
top/submodule2/jni/...
...
```

I'd defined `APP_STL` in one of the submodule `Application.mk` files, which may have been entirely ignored? Moving the definition to the top level file got the build working correctly.